# Adding SQL Stored Procedure Parameters to an existing Schema and SendPort

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2013

This biztalk Orch was working perfectly before I touched it. I did two things:

1. Modified the schema below adding 3 key, type and c_date
2. Modified my message transform so that those 3 additional parameters were mapped to the destination schema.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
   <schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <import schemaLocation=".\sqlBinding_System_x2eData.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
     <annotation>
       <appinfo>
         <fileNameHint xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/xsd">Procedure.dbo</fileNameHint>
         <references xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
           <reference targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
         </references>
       </appinfo>
     </annotation>
     <element name="Vendor_Receive_IPN_Message_sp">
       <annotation>
         <documentation>
           <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">Procedure/dbo/Vendor_Receive_IPN_Message_sp</doc:action>
         </documentation>
       </annotation>
       <complexType>
         <sequence>
           <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="data" nillable="true" type="string" />
           <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="key" nillable="true" type="string" />
           <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="type" nillable="true" type="string" />
           <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="c_date" nillable="true" type="dateTime" />
         </sequence>
       </complexType>
     </element>
     <element name="Vendor_Receive_IPN_Message_spResponse">
       <annotation>
         <documentation>
           <doc:action xmlns:doc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/documentation">Procedure/dbo/Vendor_Receive_IPN_Message_sp/response</doc:action>
         </documentation>
       </annotation>
       <complexType>
         <sequence>
           <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Vendor_Receive_IPN_Message_spResult" nillable="true" type="ns3:ArrayOfDataSet" />
           <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ReturnValue" type="int" />
         </sequence>
       </complexType>
     </element>
   </schema>
   ```

I'm getting this error:

```
The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "SendPort IPN Message to SQL" with
URL "mssql://myserver:1433//mydb?". It will be retransmitted after 
the retry interval specified for this Send Port. 
Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException: 
The start element with name "key" and namespace 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo" was unexpected. 
Please ensure that your input XML conforms to the schema for the operation.
```

What step am I missing?

Comment: Did you update your stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. And I am running a SQL profiler trace. The sproc never gets called. It doesn't get that far. If it did, you'd get a different error complaining about the procedure not having a parameter like "key".

Comment: Did you restart your host instances after deploying the updated schema?

Comment: Yup - multiple times. And I can find the schema in the admin console after I deploy from Visual studio. i can see all of my new elements in the xml.

The message is definitely getting received on the receive port. But the send/receive SQL port seems to be having an issue with the send, as the sproc never gets called and this error shows up in the application log.

Comment: Additionally... when i first created this Orchestration (before attempting to add new parameters to the sproc), I used the "Add Generated Items" option. Aside from my send and receive schema root items which it named (IPN.Schema.sqlBinding_dbo), it also added another schema with two additional root items: IPN.Schema.sqlBinding_System_x2eData with roots: ArrayOfDataSet and DataSet.  I don't understand what these are / how they are used. I didn't see my original SQL Sproc parameter referenced in there anyway, so I didn't touch them.

Comment: I also tried promoting all of the properties on the receive (right-side) of the mapper transform (which maps the receive message to the send message before going to the send sql port). Not sure I understand what that does exactly, but it was suggested. Made no difference. Don't know why it would, I wasn't promoting my single parameter previously.

Comment: Promoting means that the fields become part of the message context to allow you to route based on those fields.  Not necessary in this case.  In your Add Generated Items, which option did you use?

Comment: "Consume Adapter Service"

Then I configured / connected to the sql server and picked the stored procedure from the list.

I suppose I could scrap the orchestration and start over. But, I'd like to know how to NOT do that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add nodes to a SP schema, they have to be

1. In the same order as in the procedure (is `@key` the second param, or did you put it before `@data`?).
2. Use the same spelling and casing as the procedure (is it called `@key` or `@Key` in the procedure?).
3. Use an XSD data type that corresponds to the datatype the procedure expects (is `@key` a `(N)VARCHAR` or `(N)CHAR`?).

The error you're getting indicates either 1 or 2 isn't correct.  Show us your procedure definition to be sure.  You could also regenerate the schema for the procedure in a separate (throw away) project and compare it with your changes.

Comment: You are right on number 1. So biztalk doesn't name the parameters when it executes the stored procedure like: '@data = data, '@key = key?

Comment: If you use SQL Server Profiler, you can see exactly how it does it.  it will do `exec [SchemaName].[ProcedureName] @data = 'data_text', @key = 'key_text'` - however, part of its metadata resolution requires the parameters and XML nodes be in the same order.  I'd bet it's due to using `XmlReader`, which is forward only reading.

Comment: I never see Profiler actually attempt to run the procedure. But I did eventually find this in Profiler by accident:

exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT sp.type AS [ObjectType], modify_date AS [LastModified] 
FROM sys.all_objects AS sp 
WHERE (sp.name=@ORIGINALOBJECTNAME and SCHEMA_NAME(sp.schema_id)=@ORIGINALSCHEMANAME);

    SELECT [param].name AS [ParameterName], 
    usrt.name AS [DataType],
    SCHEMA_NAME(usrt.schema_id) AS DataTypeSchemaName...
    FROM sys.all_objects AS sp ...
Where the object = mysproc
Looks like it's validating the order before trying to execute. Interesting.

Comment: PS: Your answer actually resolved my issue! Thank you very much!


Looks like biztalk validates the schema lines up perfectly to the procedure before it even attempts to execute by pulling the procedures parameters, datatypes etc. from sys.objects.